# Estimated Standard Error of a Method of Moment Estimator, Poisson Example

Tags: standard-error, method-of-moments

For X randomly sampled from a Poisson(lambda) population, the method of moment estimate of lambda is the sample mean:

lambda_hat = X_bar

Now, say we are interested in the variance of lambda_hat (sample size = n)

Var(lambda_hat) = Var(X_bar) = Var(X) / n

*Approach 1*

Since we know the true Var(X) = lambda, we can just plug in the estimated lambda_hat into the above to get the estimated variance of lambda_hat

i.e.
Var_hat(lambda_hat) = lambda_hat / n

*Approach 2*

Sub S^2 = sample variance into Var(X),
i.e.
Var_hat(lambda_hat) = S^2 / n

I personally don't understand why approach 2 can be correct, as effectively you're estimating lambda twice in the same procedure, once with X_bar and a second time with S^2, but that's what's written in my lecture notes.

Can someone provide some insights into the two approaches?
Thank you very much!